# Boxcutter won't install

Tags: python, add-on, error

Hi There I have just changed Mac to the Mac Studio, and have had to reinstall Blender 3.64 I cannot seem to get box cutter to install at all I have two versions (paid for)

6.9 Poly Dirk and 7.19.17

6.9 will install but won't load any of the menus

I keep getting an error message (see below)

any help would be greatly appreciated

Hardops, Machine tools, mesh machine & Decal Machine all in. fine

[image]

Comment: Box cutter is a commercial addon with official support from its creators. You'd probably get better response from them directly.

Comment: did try to find a way to report this not as easy as you may think....

Comment: managed to download blender 3.4 and it installed first time 
I'll stick with this for the time until the issue is resolved - thanks for taking the time to comment